# Castle Windsor error in sitecore

Tags: dll, solr, sitecore, castle-windsor, sitecore7

I am trying to Configure an IOC Container using SOLR as my search engine for sitecore but after many attempts the configuration gets stuck at a castle windsor error. I have attached the error image below and yet I am not able to change the assemblies as required. HELP!!

[image: Castle.Windsor Error]

Comment: Did you add in the package using NuGet? Make sure it has been deployed to the /bin folder of your website.

Comment: how do I do that? I am trying to figure out ways for the same. I added **Castle.core.dll** and **castle.windsor.dll** from castle.core.3.2.0\lib\net40-client and castle.windsor.3.2.0\lib\net40-client respectively though yet the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue!! As per **point number 11** of the [blog](http://www.dansolovay.com/2013/05/setting-up-solr-with-sitecore-7.html) extract Castle.Windsor.dll and Castle.Core.dll versioned 3.1.0 (links provided in the blog itself) and paste it in your website bin directory. This will eliminate the error.

Comment: You could also set [CopyLocal=true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c.aspx) for those reference to ensure they are copied to your oiutput folder. If you used NuGet it should have been done automatically, but check what it is set to on your project.

Comment: Thank you for you response but I did not do anything with VS. I followed the guide available at Sitecore website where it is only asked to move files from folders to another.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but a manual copy should not be required if you set that value. Anyway, as long as you have it working is the main point.